# ajax delete is going inifinite loop in asp.net mvc 4 Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net MVC 4 application. In its _layout.cshtml, I need to show cart as partial view. So I used this:

```
 @{Html.RenderAction("GetCart", "Home");}
```

and then action method:

```
  [InitializeSimpleMembership]
        [ChildActionOnly]
        public ActionResult GetCart()
        {            

            var cartItems = list of cart items

            return PartialView("~/Views/shared/_Cart.cshtml", cartItems);
        }
```

In my partial view I have this:

```
@foreach (var cartItem in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <div id="POCStatus"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="details">
            <p class="item">@cartItem.ItemName</p>
        </td>
        <td class="quant">@cartItem.Quantity</td>
        <td class="price">
            <p class="amount">@cartItem.ListPrice KD</p>
        </td>
        <td class="garbage"><a id="lnkDeleteCartItem" class="RemoveLink" href="#" data-id="@cartItem.CartItemID">
                                <img src="/images/delete.png" width="16" height="16" /></a></td>

    </tr>
}
```

and jquery function:

```
 $(function () {
        // Document.ready -> link up remove event handler
        $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
            // Get the id from the link
            var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
            if (recordToDelete != '') {
                // Perform the ajax post
                $.post("/Home/DeleteCartItem", { "id": recordToDelete },
                    function (data) {
                        // Successful requests get here
                        // Update the page elements
                        if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                            $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                        } else {
                            $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
                        }
                        $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                        $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                        $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                    });
            }
        });
    });
```

but when i click delete button, it goes to infinit loop, perhaps because of Html.action in layour.cshtml.

delete function is like this:

```
  [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult DeleteCartItem(int Id)
         {
             ItemBiz.DeleteItemFromCart(Id);
             return Json("something");
     }
```

Please suggest solution to this.

Comment: return false at the end of the event

Comment: @EhsanSajjad which event ?

Comment: click event of delete of jquery

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Could you please elaborate how that can be the cause of the issue? (@)DotNetSparrow: does the MVC application get called? If you step through the process, what exactly happens?

Comment: is you action is called in loop?

Comment: Which loop? @ehsanSajjad? Could you explain when you say loop? Is the record deleted in your database?

Comment: i mean to say action is called multiple times